# Argument list too long when zipping large list of certain files in a folder

Tags: bash

I'm trying to zip a certain large number of files by creating an array of them. Then I tried to run the zip command but met with "Argument list too long" error.

```
declare -a arr=()       

fixed=5
for i in `seq 10 1 200`; do
    for j in `seq $((i+fixed)) 1 200`; do
        arr+=("${i}_${j}.xxx")
    done
done

new_arr=$(printf ",%s" "${arr[@]}")
new_arr=${new_arr:1}

zip all_data.zip {$new_arr}
```

Comment: As an alternative: you can create an empty zip file  at the beginning and add a file to that zip file, instead of making an array first and adding them all at once. Might save you a loop, unless you have need for the array for other reasons...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

extract from  `man zip` ( linux version )

```
   zip -@ foo
   will store the files listed one per line on stdin in foo.zip.
```

example from the same man page

```
   find . -name "*.[ch]" -print | zip source -@
```

So steps will be :

1. build a list off all files to be archive , format must one file name by line
2. run `zip` command

   `cat  BIG_FILENAME_LIST.txt | zip thebigziparchive -@`

Comment: I need the same functionality, but for the "ignore" list. Is there a way to do this with the "-x" option?